# Захват значений в лямбда-выражении

Tags: java, лямбда-выражение

> Лямбда-выражения должны использоваться **для захвата значений, а не переменных**. Захват значений побуждает писать код без побочных эффектов, поскольку альтернатива труднее.

Что понимается под **захватом значений** в лямбда-выражении?

Comment: лямбда-выражения может ссылаться на переменные, находящиеся в области видимости ее объявления, т.е., например, может использовать final-переменные, объявленные выше по коду, нежели она сама.

Comment: Попробуйте изменить значения int в лямбда выражении. Сразу ругнется rкомпилятор, что должно быть final или фактически final. Это и имеется ввиду.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это значит, что в лямбда-выражениях стоит использовать внешние (относительно выражения) неизменяемые значения, а не внешние переменные, значение и внутреннее состояние которых могут меняться. Под внешними неизменяемыми значениями, соответственно, подразумеваются [effectively final](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html#accessing-members-of-an-enclosing-class) локальные переменные и поля примитивных типов, а также effectively final объекты, внутреннее состояние которых не будет меняться.

Связано это с тем, что Streams и лямбда-выражения проектировались из расчета на их многопоточное использование.

Проблема с использованием переменной (`counter`) вместо значения видна в таком примере:

```
private static class Element
{
    private final int value;

    public Element(int value) { this.value = value; }

    public int getValue() { return value; }
}

private static volatile int counter = 0;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Element> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100 * 1000; i++)
    {
        list.add(new Element(1));
    }
    list.parallelStream().forEach(e -> counter += e.getValue());
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

Рассчитывать на то, что на экран будет выведено значение `100000`, не приходится, потому что налицо [race condition](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8). В моём тесте этот код смог получить правильное значение только в 299 случаях из 100 тысяч.

Это одна из причин почему локальные переменные, используемые в лямбда-выражении, должны быть effectively final. Допустимость кода

```
int localCounter = 0;
list.parallelStream().forEach(e -> localCounter += e.getValue());
```

Привела бы к race condition для локальной переменной, что стало бы новым витком проблем в многопоточном программировании на Java. Локальные переменные считаются потокобезопасными, и ломать этот принцип разработчикам Java не хотелось.

Можно "обдурить" компилятор в плане ограничения на effectively final значение таким образом:

```
int[] localCounter = { 0 };
list.parallelStream().forEach(e -> localCounter[0] += e.getValue());
System.out.println(localCounter[0]);
```

Так что "выстрелить себе в ногу" при использовании effectively final локальной переменной всё же можно. Конечно, не стоит удивляться тому, что значение опять-таки будет посчитано неправильно. На практике так делать определённо не стоит.

Да, здесь можно использовать `AtomicInteger`:

```
AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
list.parallelStream().forEach(e -> atomicInteger.addAndGet(e.getValue()));
System.out.println(atomicInteger.get());
```

Однако это убивает всю идею распараллеливания кода.

В данном случае предполагается использование связки из `map` и `reduce`:

```
int localCounter = list.parallelStream().map(e -> e.getValue()).reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b);
System.out.println(localCounter);
```

Часть с `map` и `reduce` можно записать и так:

```
.map(Element::getValue).reduce(0, Integer::sum)
```

Статью Brian Goetz (автора книги "Java Concurrency in Practice") по этому поводу можно прочитать [здесь](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ldn2/j-ldn2-pdf.pdf).

---

Однако проблемы при захвате переменных вместо значений могут возникать не только при параллельном выполнении. Например:

```
private static class Element
{
    public int x;

    public Element(int x) { this.x = x; }

    public Function<Integer, Integer> getMapper()
    {
        return (e -> e + x);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Element element = new Element(2);
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30);
    Function<Integer, Integer> function1 = element.getMapper();
    element.x = 4;
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30);
    Function<Integer, Integer> function2 = element.getMapper();
    list1 = list1.stream().map(function1).collect(Collectors.toList());
    list2 = list2.stream().map(function2).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(list1);
    System.out.println(list2);
}
```

В данном коде происходит захват переменной (не effectively final поля) `x`, из-за чего вместо ожидаемого вывода

```
[12, 22, 32]
[14, 24, 34]
```

будет выведено

```
[14, 24, 34]
[14, 24, 34]
```

При захвате же значения:

```
public Function<Integer, Integer> getMapper()
{
    int n = x;
    return (e -> e + n);
}
```

такой проблемы/ошибки не возникнет.

Answer (score 8):

Наверное, автор имел ввиду, что лямбда-выражения должны трогать не переменные, а принимать на вход значение и отдавать значения на выходе. Например:

Плохо:

```
final String string = "string";
class.method(() -> string += "abc");
```

Хорошо:

```
class.method((string) -> string += "abc");
```