# local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final при фильтрации символов в строке

Tags: java

Решаю [задачку](http://www.codewars.com/kata/duplicate-encoder/train/java). В общем, начальную строку нужно преобразовать в новую, заменив все повторяющиеся символы на правую скобочку ')', а все уникальные - на левую '('.

Мое решение:

```
public class DuplicateEncoder {
  static String encode(String word) {
    String newWord = "";
    char[] chArray = word.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
      if (word.chars().filter(num -> num == chArray[i]).count() > 1)
        { newWord = newWord + "("; }
      else 
        { newWord = newWord + ")"; }
    }
    return newWord;
  }
}
```

В нем такая ошибка:

```
/workspace/java/src/DuplicateEncoder.java:6: error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final
      if (word.chars().filter(num -> num == chArray[i]).count() > 1)
                                                    ^
1 error
```

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Вы не можете в лямба-выражениях использовать переменные, которые меняются. (можно только final и effective final). В вашем примере  i меняется в цикле, поэтому компилятор выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Захваченное лямбда-выражением локальное значение должно быть [effectively final](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/631649/183458). Этого можно добиться, например, с помощью создания `final`-переменной:

```
final ch = chArray[i];
if (word.chars().filter(num -> num == ch).count() > 1)
```

---

А вообще можно переписать решение, чтобы оно работало не за `O(n^2)`, а за `O(n)` (`n` - длина слово).
Для этого достаточно проходить по слову два раза: первый раз для подсчета количества вхождений символов и сохранения результатов в `Map`, а второй - для сбора итоговой строки по данным из `Map`.
Также для сбора строки лучше использовать `StringBuilder`, а не конкатенацию строк.

Итоговый код:

```
static String encode(String word)
{
    HashMap<Character, Integer> charToCount = new HashMap<>();
    char[] chars = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    for (char ch : chars)
    {
        int currentCount = charToCount.containsKey(ch) ? charToCount.get(ch) : 0;
        charToCount.put(ch, currentCount + 1);
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word.length());
    for (char ch : chars)
    {
        char replaceChar = charToCount.get(ch) == 1 ? '(' : ')';
        sb.append(replaceChar);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

P.S. Зашел на сайт задания - нужно ещё игнорировать регистр букв, добавил это в код

Comment: Спасибо, Ваше решение отлично работает. Исправил свое, нерациональное с О(n^2), создав final-переменную по предложенному образцу и предварительно применил метод toLowerCase() к word, формируя массив chArray. Программа заработала, но почему-то выдает неверные результаты, хотя логика лямбда-выражения здесь совсем не сложная и я не понимаю, где там допущена ошибка...

Comment: @VitaliyTretyakov да, точно, у вас `+ ")"` и `+ "("` перепутаны местами: `(` добавляется при количестве вхождений больше одного (`.count() > 1`), а `)` - если вхождение одно. Должно быть наоборот